# How to prevent jQuery.dialog from moving the dialog node to the end of DOM tree?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have used some jquery dialogs in a custom widget which is part of an HTML form.

The problem is jquery removes the dialog nodes from the form and appends them to the body node right at the end! As a result, all the form fields in the dialogs are missing in the submitted results.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

for the sake of future references, this is how i fixed this:

- set the form as appendTo option of the dialog
- give the dialog node a z-index bigger than overlay layer